# Deploy ear in embedded Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

Is it possible to deploy ear (Jersey and Metro) archive in embedded Jetty? Google shows articles and manuals only about Jetty + JBoss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, Jetty shouldn't have such a functionality.
That's because jetty was designed to be a web container only for Servlets and JSPs.
You can see the jetty as an alternative to the Tomcat web server.
So Jetty is able to process only web based stuff (read WARs).

JBoss on the other hand is a full fledged Java EE container, so it can handle ears as well.
What you've seen is probably embedding the jetty inside the jboss.
I know that Jboss has used tomcat for dealing with servlets and jsps internally, so it might be possible to switch the underlying implementation from tomcat to jetty.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

I'll add that many people deploying into things like JBoss or other full Java EE stacks really don't need the full stack and can often get away with a servlet engine plus a handful of components.  I know folks that have gone with aggregated solutions of things like jetty + open ejb to achieve a lightweight stack that does what they need without all the added Java EE bells and whistles.  For example, if you intend to have an embedded scenario then you don't need to deploy an ear you can deploy the application bit by bit, handling servlets with jetty and ejb's with openejb or whatever *bean solution you like.

If you need the full Java EE container then by all means use one...but if you are using a minor subset of those Java EE features there are other ways to assemble your application.

Comment: Great thought! But can you please elaborate a little more on how to "deploy an app bit by bit"?

Comment: Basically identify what technologies you need in your application and then mix in support for that using whatever you like.  Some things are harder than others, for example if you need CDI then you can use Weld easily for the majority of cases...and in Jetty 9.3 we'll be adding in deeper integration with Weld for the handful of outlier cases as well.  All in one solutions are great if you are using lots of the applicable technologies...but they can also be major overkill and not appropriate if you are seeking a lightweight highly scalable solution.